# Send a callback function from JSP var to Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I´m having an issue regarding a javascript method that use a callback function.
I have a jsp where I define a callback function to be invoked.

```
 <c:set var="callbackMethod" value="dispatchRFQDocument.loadDocumentGroup" scope="request"/>
```

Then from the next JSP If I invoke that callback from an onClick, everything works like a charm.

```
 <a id="documentComponentLinkId"
   href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="documentDialog.openDocumentsDialog(${callbackMethod})">
    <i id="documentsDialog" class="fa fa-folder-open-o">
        <spring:message code="label.procurement.stopProcedure.documents"/>
    </i>
</a>
```

BUT, Instead of using the onClick event, I want to bind the event on my Javascript and invoke there the callback. The callback method cannot be invoked anymore, since is a literal.

In my JSP

```
   <script>
         var callbackMethod = "${callbackMethod}";
   </script>
```

And in the Javascript

```
var initListener = function () {
    $('#documentComponentLinkId').click(function () {
        documentDialog.openDocumentsDialog(callbackMethod);
    });
};
```

Any suggestion?

Regards.

Comment: Just for testing, write an `alert(dispatchRFQDocument.loadDocumentGroup);` to make sure your method exists before passing it to init listener.

Comment: I did and alert(callbackMethod) return "dispatchRFQDocument.loadDocumentGroup" problem is, that when I declare as variable is not a function anymore

Comment: Paul, you're not understanding. Forget the JS variable for a second because **that's just a string**. For this thing to finally work `dispatchRFQDocument.loadDocumentGroup` has to exist (not as a string but) as a JS **function object**. So, when I asked you to `alert(dispatchRFQDocument.loadDocumentGroup);` I meant to write exactly that because it seems that function does not exist and will output `[undefined]`. You need to solve that first.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the callback method directly to `openDocumentsDialog()` just like you did before.

```
var initListener = function () {
    $('#documentComponentLinkId').click(function () {
        documentDialog.openDocumentsDialog(${callbackMethod});
    });
};
```

Comment: Without define a js variable?. How is that possible?, and If I define the variable as I did, I have this the error "error callback() is not a function"

Comment: Well, have you made sure `dispatchRFQDocument.loadDocumentGroup` exists before you define your `initListener`? And, no, there's no need to declare a JS variable just for the assignment.

Comment: this is  not a syntax that Javascript can understand ${callbackMethod}. I´m missing something here?. Thx

Comment: When the browser receives that JSP file, ${callbackMethod} would have already been replaced by the actual JS function call. This would happen on the server before the HTML response is sent to the browser. That's how JSPs work so no issues there. Yes, your IDE may be complaining about syntax highlighting issues as JS doesn't understand `{}` but all this works like a template file with what finally gets rendered on the browser (after placeholder values `${}` have been replaced) determining if it's the correct syntax or not.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your variable **callbackMethod** to a string.

Actually instead of doing that you have to set it to the function definition.

I think below should work fine:

> var callbackMethod = dispatchRFQDocument.loadDocumentGroup

Comment: ok but again, the problem is that I need to pass this variable from page to another. I´m using module pattern, and variables must be part of the page. I cannot use form my js a var defined out of the page that include the var. And this page is a generic component

Comment: And paste that is not working    ReferenceError: dispatchRFQDocument is not defined
 

var callbackMethod = dispatchRFQDocument.loadDocumentGroup

Comment: First you have to make sure that the required method exists in the given scope. If not, then you have to access that method (if private) via the privileged method of your module.

Comment: Internally privileged Method of module can access its private variable and private method as they come under their static scope.